# Query if relation is defined before whereHas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Consider the following eloquent model:

```
$itemModel->whereHas('location.country', function($q2) use ($value){
     $q2->where('id', $value);
});
```

When I run this, I get an (expected) exception saying

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::country()
```

Is there any way I can check the existence of this relation before I execute the whereHas query?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to use `whereHas`, multiple relations in the query is for eager loading.
You can try :

```
$item->whereHas('location',function($query) use ($value){
      $query->whereHas('country')->where('id',$value);
});
```

Relations nesting was not implemented for whereHas